Restrict admin permission set assignment when user has not the admin profile
How can I restrict users in my org to assign other users the admin permission set when they do not have the admin profile?

Did you look at Delegated Admins feature?  This allows you to allowList only certain PS that a delegated admin can assign

Unfortunately, there is no way at the moment to do it with OOTB functionality and Apex triggers are also not supported for PermissionSetAssignent.
You can remove "Assign Permission Set" permission from those users and prevent them option all together.
In general if user has "Assign Permission Sets" or "View Setup and Configuration" then it means that they are Admin.
